# Overriding DNS entries per process

Tags: dns

I'm trying to have local tests working without running consul as DNS server. Which means I'm trying to map `web.service.consul` to `localhost`.

I've tried creating `HOSTALIASES` file but it seems it doesn't support dot in the alias name. I also tried playing with `LOCALDOMAIN` and `RES_OPTIONS=ndots:10` but can't get this to work.

```
$ HOSTALIASES=/tmp/ha RES_OPTIONS=ndots:10 LOCALDOMAIN='consul' curl web.services.consul:8080
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: web.services.consul
$
```

Where `/tmp/ha` is

```
web.services.consul 127.0.0.1
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, `env LOCALDOMAIN=microsoft.com curl www` gets the goods (bads?) for me. I'm not sure a fully qualified `web.services.consul` will fly, as that would be looking for `web.services.consul.consul` with your `LOCALDOMAIN` setting.

Comment: FWIW in reasonably recent **`curl` specifically** `--resolve` overrides other resolution and uses exactly what you specify. In any other program that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Put in `/tmp/ha`:

```
web localhost
```

then you cam call curl with:

```
 HOSTALIASES=/tmp/ha curl web:8080
```

Format of `HOSTALIASES` is explained in `hostname(7)` - it is not a same thing as `/etc/hosts` !

If you can edit `/etc/hosts`, you could simply put `127.0.0.1 web.services.consul` in it and then just use your test programs normally... Another way would be use `iptables ... -j REDIRECT` to force traffic to go to localhost instead... But both of those require root access.

Comment: Thanks. However this does not work for me with the above command line. From what I understand you cannot have aliases with `.` in the `HOSTALIAS` file.